# How to enable camera and microphone in packaged application for Chrome OS or Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, getusermedia, google-chrome-os

I'm testing scenario where I call a hangouts web page in separate window but application doesn't have access to microphone and camera - buttons are red and message says that "Hangouts can't use the selected microphone/camera".

I have included in permissions `"audioCapture"` and `"videoCapture"`.

What has to be done to make it work?

**Edit:**

After allowing media app has access to camera and microphone - I can see that in settings of hangouts but picture and voice are not transmitted over the hangouts to other participants. Is there something I have to set for streaming media?

I already have this piece of code:

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true },
            function (stream) {
                mediaStream = stream;
            },
            function (error) {
                console.error("Error trying to get the stream:: " + error.message);
            });
```

Comment: You are embedding Hangouts in a `<webview>`, correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly like you said.

Comment: Maybe you are opening the stream for the app itself, and the embedded page can't get it because it's exclusive access?

Comment: I don't quite inderstand (I'm new at packaged apps). I can say that as a Chrome extension it works but as a packaged app on Chrome OS media are not transmitted.

Comment: My point is, this code should NOT be in your app; Hangouts should request `GetUserMedia` itself, you only need to take care of that permission request. If this code is in your app, it may be conflicting with Hangouts.

Comment: I uderstand. Is it still applicable if the same app works as a Chrome Extension but opens in separate window (chrome.app.window.create)?

Answer (score 5):

If you need to provide audio/video for a `<webview>`-embedded page, requiring `"audioCapture"`/`"videoCapture"` permissions is not enough.

To use those, the page requests permission to the browser. In normal Chrome you'll see an infobar allowing the user to allow/deny the request.

`<webview>` does not show those elements, instead it [raises an event](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#event-permissionrequest) and it's up to the app to allow/deny it:

> **`permissionrequest`**
>
> Fired when the guest page needs to request special permission from the embedder.
>
> The following example code will grant the guest page access to the `webkitGetUserMedia` API. Note that an app using this example code must itself specify `audioCapture` and/or `videoCapture` manifest permissions:
>
> ```
> webview.addEventListener('permissionrequest', function(e) {
>   if (e.permission === 'media') {
>     e.request.allow();
>   }
> });
> ```

Comment: I am developing a Chromebook kiosk app that needed access to the microphone and camera; this snippet plus the `audioCapture` and `videoCapture` permissions in `manifest.json` worked perfectly.

Comment: For a chrome extension, you can't add the videoCapture permission it seems.