# React Webcam component doesn`t work inside chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, webcam

I have a problem with React Webcam - https://github.com/mozmorris/react-webcam

In desktop app everything works great - tried it with create-react-app 2.0 recently - web app starts, asks for permission to use camera and when user allows, camera starts, screenshots work, everything is fine.

However when i copy the exact same component inside our chrome extension there is a problem. When user clicks "change profile photo" the extension opens new page:

> chrome-extension://ebjbbcedbjkaagbpbkdlhlnbeoehjmgn/page.html#/uploadsnapshot

The Uploadsnapshot component renders fine, no visible errors (nothing in the console), in the html there is the React-Webcam component element:

```
<video autoplay="" width="132" height="132" class="UploadPhotoSnapshot__webcam__3VOiZ" playsinline=""></video>
```

But the camera doesn`t start and no "allow / block camera" popup appears.

I searched for solutions, tried adding "audioCapture" and "videoCapture" to permissions in my "manifest.json" as mentioned here:
[How to enable camera and microphone in packaged application for Chrome OS or Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089359/how-to-enable-camera-and-microphone-in-packaged-application-for-chrome-os-or-chr)

It still will not ask for permission to use camera and will not start.

I also tried using different component: https://github.com/mabelanger/react-html5-camera-photo and got error when the component loads:

> onCameraError DOMException: Invalid security origin

My component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Webcam from "react-webcam";
import styles from "./UploadPhotoSnapshot.css";

class UploadPhotoSnapshot extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activeImg: null,
            imagesArr: []
        }
    }

    setRef = webcam => {
        this.webcam = webcam;
    };
    capture = () => {
        let shot = this.webcam.getScreenshot();
        let newArr = [...this.state.imagesArr];
        newArr.unshift(shot);
        this.setState({
            activeImg: shot,
            imagesArr: newArr
        });
    };        

    render() {

        const videoConstraints = {
            width: 132,
            height: 132,
            facingMode: "user"
        };
        let imagesPreview = null;
        if (this.state.imagesArr.length > 0) {
            imagesPreview = (
                <div className={styles.webcamArrScroll}>
                    {this.state.imagesArr.map((image, index) => (
                       <img className={styles.webcamArrImg} src={image} alt="" key={index} />
                    ))}
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div className={styles.webcamDiv}>
                <Webcam
                    audio={false}
                    height={132}
                    ref={this.setRef}
                    screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
                    width={132}
                    videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
                    className={styles.webcam}
                />
                <button className={styles.webcamBtnTakePhoto} onClick={this.capture}>Take a snapshot</button>
                <div className={styles.webcamArr}>
                    {imagesPreview}
                </div>                
                <div className={styles.buttons}>
                    <button className={styles.buttonText}>Cancel</button>
                    <button className={styles.buttonSetPhoto} onClick={this.hasFileUploaded}>Set a profile photo</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default UploadPhotoSnapshot;
```

my manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "DEV",
    "description": "dev",
    "version": "4.0.0",
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://apis.google.com https://www.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
    "default_locale": "en",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "/icons/icon_48.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "/icons/icon_16.png",
        "32": "/icons/icon_32.png",
        "48": "/icons/icon_48.png",
        "64": "/icons/icon_64.png",
        "128": "/icons/icon_128.png"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "app/*",
        "/images/*",
        "favicon.ico"
    ],
    "sandbox": {
        "pages": ["page.html"]
    },
    "commands": {
        "_execute_browser_action": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Alt+P"
            }
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "identity",
        "audioCapture",
        "videoCapture",
        "identity.email"        
    ],
    "oauth2": {
        "client_id": "12345.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "scopes": [
            "email",
            "profile",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"
        ]
    },

"key": "12345"
}
```

Do i somehow have to invoke the "allow / deny camera" popup inside the Chrome extension component?
Would be very gratefull for any ideas/ help / hint / solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to [this Chromium bug](https://crbug.com/160337) that makes the extension crash (although you don't get exactly the same error).

See a solution for a possible duplicate here: [Chrome Extension - getUserMedia throws "NotAllowedError: Failed due to shutdown"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991321/chrome-extension-getusermedia-throws-notallowederror-failed-due-to-shutdown)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and fixed it.
It all came down to
 `"sandbox": {
        "pages": ["page.html"]
    },` 
in the manifest.json file. When you use "sandbox", the content security origin is blocking everything.
 I deleted it and everything is working. Camera, sound recording, screenshots.

Comment: My `manifest.json` does not include a `sandbox` entry and I'm still running into the same problem. Are you requesting permissions inside of your `background` script? Can you share the contents of that script here as a reference?